# What is the definition of $G/R$ (the classes of all equivalence classes in G) symbolically?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let *R* be an equivalence relation on *G*. If $a\in G$, then the equivalence class of *a* is the class of all those elements of *G* which that are equivalent to *a*; that is
$\bar{a}=\{b\in G|b\sim a\}$.

Now I just want a symbolic explanation for $G/R$ --the class of all the equivalence classes in *G*.

Comment: $\{\bar{a}:a\in G\}$... well I don't really know what you mean by "symbolic explanation".

Answer (score 3):

$$G/R = \{\bar{a} \mid a \in G\}$$

I.e., it is the collection of all the equivalence classes in $G$ under the equivalence relation $R$.  Note that although an equivalence class may contain many elements of $G$ it occurs only once in the set I have written since it is not a multiset.  (An equivalence class is identical to itself; picking a different representative to write under the "bar" does not change the equivalence class.  This is the property of equivalence classes that one keeps checking -- that selection of particular representatives to write under the bar doesn't actually change the value of an expression.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like:

$$G/R = \{A \in \mathcal{P}(G) \mid A \neq \emptyset \text{ and for all } x \in A, y \in G; y \in A \Leftrightarrow x \sim y\}$$

Where $\mathcal{P}(G)$ is the power set of $G$.